# EventListener not working before certain function

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

the 'click' event does not happen when a put a function after :

```
<pre>
 <body> 
   <section class="page">
      <label for="name">Nome: </label>
      <input type="text" name="nome">
      <input type="button" value="Adicionar na lista">
   </section>

   <script>
      var autores = [{nome:'CCarlos'},{nome:'Daniel'}];
      var botao = document.querySelector('input[type=button]');
      botao.addEventListener('click',aviso);
      imprimir();
      function aviso(){
         alert('aasf');
      }

      function imprimir(){
         var pagina = document.querySelector('.page');
         for(i in autores){
           enter code herepagina.innerHTML += `<p>${autores[i].nome}</p>`;
         }
      }   
   </script>
</body>
```

and when i remove i works just fine, have no ideia why is this happening

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking?  "when a put a function after :" - "when i remove i works just fine". is not making sense.  Perhaps provide a this works / this doesn't work example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're changing the html using `innerHTML +=` that destroys everything inside `pagina` and creates everything anew. It means that your event listener goes bye bye.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `pagina.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', \`<p>....</p>\`)` instead of `pagina.innerHTML += ...`

Answer (score -1):

Is that your actual code? you have this actual line or it's just a copy/paste error?

```
enter code herepagina.innerHTML += `<p>${autores[i].nome}</p>`;
```

if so, I guess you have some syntax error on your browser's console. Chage it to

```
pagina.innerHTML += `<p>${autores[i].nome}</p>`;
```

if it was a copy/paste error, check the browser's console if there's any error